# MSBuild. Extend standard xsd schema

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xsd, msbuild, csproj

I need add `<CustomItem>` in `<ItemGroup>` with mandatory metadata. Visual Studio autocomplete works with standard elements of files with header:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

How can I write local file with schema and include in MSBuild file?

Answer (score 1):

The schema is only used for VS' xml editor completion logic. Since VS 2017 / MSBuild 15, it isn't even necessary to include any XML namespace to get the "default" completion logic for common properties and items.

You can create any property, item or task without adding a schema file.

Comment: I wrote down my own <Item> in build scripts and I want autocompletion to help me write my own elements to avoid errors.

Comment: Then I think it's best to create a feedback/problem item at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com since I think that msbuild project file autocomplete is now driven by the xsd file included in the VS installation.